# Ruby on Rails - string to array weird formatting in email parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I can get the body of an email in String format like so

> body = params[:plain]

And when I output it, it looks like:

> Hi there.
>
> -- 
>   John B.
>
> Sent from my iPhone.

Now, when I try and split by newline `body.split("\n")` I get:

> --- 
>   - ! 'Hi there.' 
>   - ''  
>   - ! '-- ' 
>   - John B. 
>   - ''  
>   - Sent from my iPhone.

I don't really understand the extra hyphens and bangs. Any thoughts?

Also if I do `body[2]` I get `--`, but `body.index("--")` returns me nothing.

UPDATE

In my ReceivingMails controller:

```
...

def create
  body = params[:plain]
  parsed_body = parse_body(body)
  Comment.new(:content => parsed_body)
end

private

def parse_body(body)
  split = body.split("\n")
  sig_index = split.index("-- ")
  return split[0, sig_index].join("\n")
end
```

In my view, comments are shown as: `<%= simple_format(comment.content)%>`

UPDATE 2

When I do something like, `body.split("\n").to_s` I get what the expected array should look like (as String): `["Hi there. ", "", "-- ", "John B.", "", "Sent from my iPhone."]`

Comment: It's serializing the array to YAML, although I don't know why.

Comment: hmmm if that the case, how can I deserialize back to normal? 
I found this article that I'm working through http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/

Comment: Without any context it's difficult to know how to help. If you've serialized it to, say, a DB, just read it back in. How you're displaying it and all that matter--and we don't know.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what you're asking or looking for. All I'm trying to do is perform some array operations on a local variable, `body`, before assigning that variable to a model attribute in the DB. I'll add whatever operations I'm doing in an update

Answer (score 0):

I don't think params[:plain] is actually a string - I think you should test it to find out what it actually is. For example try:

`puts params[:plain].class`